# Can parameter expansions be run on command substitution output in one step?

Tags: bash

I keep getting `bad substitution`

```
pages1=${`pdftk "$1" dump_data | grep NumberOfPages`#*:}
```

Is it possible to keep this one statement without having to do what's below?

```
pages1=`pdftk "$1" dump_data | grep NumberOfPages`
pages1=${pages1#*:}
```

Comment: Curly braces have a lot more uses in bash than only parameter expansion (which is what the thing you're trying to do here is called). I've tried to edit the summary to explain to folks who are reading more precisely what is is you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible the way you're doing but you can replace `grep` by this `awk` to get your output in single command:

```
pages1=$(pdftk "$1" dump_data | awk '/NumberOfPages/{sub(/^[^:]*:/, ""); print}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `read` built-in with a process substitution rather than an assignment statement.

```
IFS=: read pages1 _ < <(pdftk "$1" dump_data | grep NumberOfPages)
```

Everything up to the first `:` will be assigned to `pages1`; everything after the first colon will be assigned to `_`, whose value you can simply ignore. (There's nothing special about the name `_`; you can use any name you like, such as `rest`, `tail`, etc.)

If you are using `bash` 4.2 or later, you can turn on the `lastpipe` option and simply pipe the output of `grep` to the read built-in.

```
shopt -s lastpipe
pdftk "$1" dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | IFS=: read pages1 _
```

---

Irrelevant to `bash`, but `zsh` supports this type of parameter expansion chaining.

```
% pages1=${$(echo a:b:c)#*:}
% echo $pages1
b:c
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using grep you can use sed:

```
pages1=$(pdftk "$1" dump_data | sed -ne '/NumberOfPages/{ s/^.\?[^:]*://; p; }')
```

Note: `s/^.\?[^:]*://` emulates `${1#*:}` more than `s/^.*://`.